# Cant install python36 through epel-release, package python36 not found

Tags: python, python-3.6, centos7

I cant install python 36 on below version of centos.
CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)

NAME="CentOS Linux"

VERSION="7 (Core)"

ID="centos"

ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"

VERSION_ID="7"

PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"

ANSI_COLOR="0;31"

CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"

HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"

BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"

REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"

REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)

CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)

Pytho34 is available but not python36.

## yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="epel" info python34

Failed to set locale, defaulting to C

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror

Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

- epel: mirrors.kernel.org

Available Packages

Name        : python34

Arch        : x86_64

Version     : 3.4.10

Release     : 2.el7

Size        : 51 k

Repo        : epel/x86_64

Summary     : Version 3 of the Python programming language aka Python 3000

URL         : http://www.python.org/

License     : Python

Description : Python 3 is a new version of the language that is incompatible with the 2.x

```
        : line of releases. The language is mostly the same, but many details, especially

        : how built-in objects like dictionaries and strings work, have changed


        : considerably, and a lot of deprecated features have finally been removed.
```

## yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="epel" info python36

Failed to set locale, defaulting to C

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror

Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

- epel: mirrors.kernel.org

Error: No matching Packages to list

I know other methods to do python36 installation on centos7, but how to do with epel repo?

Comment: Same here .Looks like an issue with the repo

Answer (score 2):

RHEL 7.7 added Python 3.6. Python 3.6 was removed from EPEL 7 to comply with the EPEL guidelines: No RHEL packages in EPEL. Apparently, each time RHEL releases and CentOS does not yet, there can be a period of breakage. See the [discussion on EPEL mailing list](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/archives/list/epel-devel@lists.fedoraproject.org/message/GUSLTD5AJWFEGBFK5EYFVH3LHQVHUBAP/) and [original bug report about this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1739804).

Answer (score 0):

Same here, apparently they removed it by mistake? Temporary workaround is to use outdated repo. I've filed a bug, you can observe it on redhat bugzilla: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1740053